# Trying to get slideout.js working in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I can't seem to get slideout.js working inside of a wordpress installation, and to be very honest I'm crap with JavaScript so it is very possible that what I am asking has a simple answer. Here is what I have

Works as expected like this in regular ol' HTML:

```
<script src="assets/js/slideout.js"></script>
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var slideout = new Slideout({
      'panel': document.getElementById('panel'),
      'menu': document.getElementById('menu'),
      'side': 'right'
    });

    document.querySelector('.js-slideout-toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
      slideout.toggle();
    });

    document.querySelector('.menu').addEventListener('click', function(eve) {
      if (eve.target.nodeName === 'A') { slideout.close(); }
    });
  };
</script>
```

I have it queued up in the functions.php file like this:

```
function theme_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script ('flexslider-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/flexslider.js', array('jquery'),'',true);
    wp_enqueue_script ('slideout', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/slideout.js', array('jquery'),'',true);
    wp_enqueue_script ('theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/theme.js', array('jquery'),'',true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js');
```

And I'm trying to call it in in theme.js like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var slideout = new Slideout({
      'panel': document.getElementById('panel'),
      'menu': document.getElementById('menu'),
      'side': 'right'
    });

    document.querySelector('.js-slideout-toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
      slideout.toggle();
    });

    document.querySelector('.menu').addEventListener('click', function(eve) {
      if (eve.target.nodeName === 'A') { slideout.close(); }
    });
});
```

I'm 97% sure the problem lies in how I'm trying to add it to theme.js, but like I said I'm very inexperienced with JS and especially with how JS works inside of wordpress so any help I can get would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any errors or specific issues?

Comment: Check your browser console for errors or 404s on your JS files.

Comment: Nope no errors in the browser consoles, No issues either.

Answer (score 1):

I really feel like an idiot. The JS was linked up right, but there was some CSS elements that were being rendered differently on the WP version vs the local PHP version. I finally pulled up two console windows from each to compare side by side to see differences and thats how I figured it out. If anyone else is having the same issue make sure you check the CSS. The stuff pre-packaged from the developer conflicts with each other if you use their stylesheet/source code in wordpress. Especially in my case if you were trying to get the slideout from the right hand side.